# How to add custom form to action hook in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to add reCaptcha to custom forms ( two custom forms ), well the first thing i did was to install the recaptcha plugin, it works great on all the standard form on the website.

My two custom forms are register form very a like to the normal /register/ on Wordpress, Which is working the recaptcha on, but on the custom once not working.

What i want is to add this two custom forms somehow to the standard hook of WP like the register form so the plugin will recognize them as a default form.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is finding out what the plugin defines as "standard forms" as you called it (via an action/filter hook? or jQuery?). Then customize your script accordingly.